# телеграм бот выполняет только первое условие (/help) игнорирую второе (Артём правда)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot
import random

# Создаем экземпляр бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'пока я умею только говорить правда неправда для этого напишите Артём правда и дальше сообщение')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def check_message(message):
    # Получение первых двух слов из сообщения
    words = message.text.split()[:2]

    # Проверка, содержится ли "Артём" в первых двух словах
    if len(words) >= 2 and words[0].lower() == 'Артём' and words[1].lower() == 'правда':


        # Генерация случайного числа для выбора ответа "правда" или "неправда"
        import random
        answer = random.choice(["правда ", "неправда "])
        qwerrtt = "думаю... "
        remaining_message = ' '.join(message.text.split()[2:])

        ttyyu = qwerrtt + answer + remaining_message

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ttyyu)
```

Comment: `words[0].lower() == 'Артём'` думаю нужно вот тут посмотреть, потому что `артём != Артём`